# Define version as compiler option

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

If I define the current version of my web app via a compiler arg is that considered bad form?

```
-define=CONFIG::VERSION,1.005
```

Should I really be loading an XML file with this info?

Just want to use the best approach.

Thank you!

Comment: Best is subjective.  Since you have not shared any information on to your business case and why you care about versioning your app or what the app needs to do with the version it is impossible for us to guide you on what may be best for your situation.

Comment: I only use the version # to display it in the "About" section. That's the only place I use it so that's why I decided not to implement a full VersionControl class.

Comment: My impulse is that I wouldn't use conditional compilation for a value you want to display in your app.  So, an external file would be my preference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Versioning via defining compile parameters is the best approach in my opinion as well because it's the simplest way to integrate as3 runtime-accessbile version and build scripts. It's also quite extendable without modifying existing code:

1. You have version in as3 code without loading (or embedding) and parsing xml configs.
2. You can easily pass version in build script and if you use ant `buildnumber` target it will automatically increment version and store it in the external file.
3. Storing version in external file in version control system automatically marks the sources so you can easily check out it later for the given version.
4. You can still add the creation of version.xml file in build script (and place it in the build directory for example) later if you need to share version with other modules or server.

I use such approach for several years in different projects (from small test applications to big online games) and it always works fine for me.